# pasting Jpeg output in directory in R

Tags: r, paste

I have function which performs scatter plot and I want to paste the results(Jpeg images) in D:/output but instead it is pasting in D:/.I want my results to be pasted on D:/output.
Please do help me.

```
setwd("D:/output") 
IDs <- colnames(raw.expression) 
for (i in 1:(dim(raw.expression)[2]-1)) 
  { for( j in i:(dim(raw.expression)[2]) ) 
    { if (i != j) 
      { jpeg(file=paste("/",IDs[i],"gegen",IDs[j],".jpg",sep="")) 
        correlation <- round(cor(raw.expression[,i],raw.expression[,j]),2)
        maximum <- max(log2(raw.expression[,i])) 
        minimum <- min(log2(raw.expression[,i]))  
        plot(log2(raw.expression[,i]),log2(raw.expression[,j])
          ,xlab=IDs[i],ylab=IDs[j],p‌​ch='.'
          ,text (maximum-2,minimum+0.5
          ,labels=paste("R = ",correlation,sep=""),pos=4,offset=0)) 
        dev.off() 
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `jpeg('D:/output/filename.jpg'); plot(1); dev.off()` or something similar?

Comment: alternatively - `setwd(D:/output)` then run your plotting code.

Comment: @Chase I tried setwd("D:/output") but it is printing in D:/

Comment: so you're saying it returns an error when you run `setwd()`? What is the error? Does `D:/output` exist?

Comment: @Chase it is returning any error..there is D:/output

Comment: setwd("D:/output")
  IDs <- colnames(raw.expression)
  for (i in 1:(dim(raw.expression)[2]-1))
  {
    for( j in i:(dim(raw.expression)[2]) )
    {
      if (i != j)
      {          
        jpeg(file=paste("/",IDs[i],"_gegen_",IDs[j],".jpg",sep=""))
        correlation <- round(cor(raw.expression[,i],raw.expression[,j]),2)

Comment: maximum <- max(log2(raw.expression[,i]))
        minimum <- min(log2(raw.expression[,i]))
        plot(log2(raw.expression[,i]),log2(raw.expression[,j]),xlab=IDs[i],ylab=IDs[j],pch='.',text           (maximum-2,minimum+0.5,labels=paste("R = ",correlation,sep=""),pos=4,offset=0))
        dev.off()
      }
       
    }
  }

Comment: @Cahse My code is splitted in two parts in the above comments

Comment: I added your code to the question. Please review and make sure I got the line breaks / spacing right. I might suggest you remove all of the for loop business, try to get the plot to save where you want with a single plot, then build it up from there...

Comment: after running the `setwd()` line, what are the results of `getwd()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
jpeg(file=paste("/",IDs[i],"gegen",IDs[j],".jpg",sep=""))
```

you prepend the filename with a "/" which would indicate that this is an absolute path, starting at the top of the file structure.  I'm guessing on windows, this would be the top of the current drive letter, so it is going into `D:` rather than the current working directory `D:/output`.